# In C, why should you call pthread_join only after initializing a list of created threads?

Tags: c, multithreading

I understand what both do, but I have a question about the behavior of pthread_join.

I noticed this pattern is pretty common in C (mind the pseudocode):

```
for i in some range:
    thread[i] = pthread_create (...)

for i in some range:
    pthread_join(&thread[i]...)
```

Why can't it happen at the same time? e.g:

```
for i in some range:
    thread[i] = pthread_create (...)
    pthread_join(&thread[i]...)
```

Comment: If you do it like that, you might as well just call all of those functions in sequence and avoid the threading overhead

Comment: note that your code looks more like C++ython to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because if you do that, all threads run sequentially, since `pthread_join` waits for thread termination.

So you're losing the benefit of running the threads at the same time, simply.

Comment: I see. Does it mean that once you run the pthread_join loop, it will wait for the first one to finish and then for the second one, and so on, even if they don't necessarily finish in that order? e.g. will it only cleanup thread N after it has cleaned up all N-1 threads, even if N finished first?

Comment: yes, join is sequential. the idea of `join` in that context is to wait for _all_ threads to finish. If the thread is already finished when `pthread_join` is called, then it returns immediately.